# Please complete this number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

(This is my original puzzle) Can you work out the number that fills in the question mark?

1,9,216,10000,?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next number is:

> 759,375

Because:

> Formula is each triangular number raised to the next power. So 1 is the first triangular number, 1^1 = 1, 3 is the second triangular number, so 3^2 = 9, 6 is the third, and 6^3 = 216, then 10^4 and finally 15^5